# Cómo impedir save o update sobre una entidad hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, groovy

Quiero crear una entidad sobre la que no se deben hacer inserts ni updates de ningún tipo, se me ocurren dos formas de hacer esto:

Usando la etiqueta insertable = false y updatable = false sobre cada columna

```
@Entity
@Table(name = users)
class Users {
    @Column(name= 'name' insertable=false, updatable=false)
    String name;
}
```

Esto no me gusta aunque funciona porque tengo que poner esas etiquetas en todas las columnas y a mí me gustaría hacerlo a nivel de clase, para esto se me ocurre utilizar la anotación @Inmutable de hibernate

```
@Entity
@Inmutable
@Table(name = users)
class Users {
    @Column(name= 'name')
    String name;
}
```

Esta etiqueta me permite hacer un get sobre la entidad pero no poder modificar esos valores más adelante.

**¿La etiqueta inmutable anula la persistencia de hibernate o se puede hacer save de alguna manera?
¿Existe alguna otra etiqueta que pueda usar a nivel de clase en una entidad que me permita modificar objetos de la entidad pero no insertar ni actualizar en base de datos?**

Comment: Osea que solo quieres consultarla?

Comment: Si, más concretamente se van a hacer consultas masivas sobre esa entidad pero bajo ningún concepto se puede insertar ni actualizar ningún dato por lo que quiero "ahorrarme" esas funciones de hibernate para evitar liadas de ningún tipo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En efecto, la etiqueta inmutable no te permite persistir la entidad en base de datos.

Puede modificar los objetos de una entidad sin tener que insertarlos en base de datos, solo se inserta en base de datos cuando ejecutas el método persist. Por lo tanto todas las modificaciones que hagas sobre el objeto quedarán reflejadas en memoria, si no quieres almacenar las modificaciones simplemente no hagas persist del objeto.

Comment: Pues ya está, va a ser la mejor solución. Si quiero alterar los datos consultados siempre los puedo pasar a un pojo o dto y así me garantizo de que no se inserte nunca por ese medio.
Sé que puedo simplemente no persistir la entidad pero si puedo impedirlo entiendo que gano 2 cosas:
1. Evitar liadas en el futuro porque llegue un programador nuevo y haga un insert de algún tipo.
2. Ganar en rendimiento al evitar que hibernate ponga esas entidades en el persistence context ya que se usará esa entidad para consultas masivas y todo segundo que se pueda ganar pues bienvenido sea.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es mapear una **vista** en lugar de una **tabla**

Supongamos que tenemos nuestra tabla Usuario, asi que creamos la vista siendo una consulta de nuestra tabla original

```
CREATE VIEW `UsuarioView` AS
    SELECT * FROM Usuario
```

Y en nuestro mapeo hacemos referencia a la vista

```
@Entity
@Inmutable
@Table(name = "UsuarioView")
class Users {
    @Column(name= 'name')
    String name;
}
```

Cuando hibernate cree las consulta simplemente hara el query con con el nombre de la vista que sera valido. Pero cuando alguien quiera persistir o actualizar una entidad de este tipo recibira una fea excepción y no podrá hacerlo.

Comment: Es una solución que le podría vale a alguien perfectamente pero en mi caso es inviable porque la tabla tiene varios millones de registros y lanzar las querys para cargar la vista sería una liada pero en condiciones normales es una solución perfectamente valida.

Comment: @Blazerg en efecto la solución del Inmutable es la mejor, pero siempre es bueno tener alternativas ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir las siguientes líneas al código del repositorio:

```
@Override
@RestResource(exported = false)
Users save(Users entity);
```